# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when trying to compile ico contract using compile.js function in my blockchain project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blockchain, solidity

Below is the solidity code of the ico contract which is called using the compile.js class, it deployed correctly on remix, but tend to give error in vscode by not generating the json files in a diffrent folder.
i need help, or just guide me on easy steps of generating json files of the below smart contract that can be usable in my dapp. thanks

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }
    function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }
    function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}



contract ICO is ERC20Interface{
    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint public decimals;
    uint public bonusEnds;
    uint public icoEnds;
    uint public icoStarts;
    uint public allContributers;
    uint allTokens;
    address admin;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    function ICO () public {
        name = "Demo Coin";
        decimals = 18;
        symbol = "DC";
        bonusEnds = now + 2 weeks;
        icoEnds = now + 4 weeks;
        icoStarts = now;
        allTokens = 100000000000000000000 * 100;   // equals 100 ether * 100 DC
        admin = (msg.sender);
        balances[msg.sender] = allTokens;
    }


    // 100 DC token == 1 Ether
    function buyTokens() public payable {

        uint tokens;

        if(now <= bonusEnds) {
            tokens =  msg.value.mul(125);  // 25% bonus
        }else {
            tokens =  msg.value.mul(100); // no bunus
        }

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        allTokens = allTokens.add(tokens);
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokens);

        allContributers++;
    }



    // needed for erc20 interface
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return allTokens;
    }
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }
    // --->



    function myBalance() public constant returns (uint){
        return (balances[msg.sender]);
    }

    function myAddress() public constant returns (address){
        address myAdr = msg.sender;
        return myAdr;
    }

    function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    


}
```

below is the js code, the code which if called, the above smart contract of ico will be compiled as planed.

```
const path = require ('path');
const solc = require ('solc');
const fs = require ('fs-extra');


const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');

fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const icoPath = path.resolve (__dirname, 'contracts', 'ICO.sol');

const source = fs.readFileSync(icoPath, 'utf8');

const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);


for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(':', '') + '.json'),
    output[contract]
  );
}
```